# Primeface wizard problem showing and hidding tabs

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Im working with Primefaces wizard component and I need to show or hide a tab depending a variable.

Im doing this:

```
<p:wizard id="solWizard"
                      flowListener="#{wizardBean.onFlowProcess}"                      
                      widgetVar="wizardWidget" 
                    >
<p:tab id="tab1" title="Tab 1">
...
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="tab2" title="Tab 2">
...
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="tab3" rendered=#{wizardBean.renderTab}  title="Tab 3">
    ...
  </p:tab>
</p:wizard>
```

Tab number 3 has a render condition. RenderTab is a boolean of wizardBean.

There are two ways to change the value of renderTab, one option is with a checkbox in the first tab, and that works great, every change to renderTab show and hide the tab (the checkbox has an ajax so I could update the tab).

The second way is in the bean, inside the onFlowProcess method, in the logic of the method when you go from tab 1 to tab 2 the boolean renderTab is changed, but the tab doesnt suffer any change

This is the onflowProcess method:

```
public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {
    this.wizardStep = event.getNewStep();
       
    try{
                  
         switch (event.getOldStep()) {
             case "tab1":{
                 rendeTab=Boolean.TRUE;
                 PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("@form");
         }
...
```

As you can see, im updating the form with PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("@form"), but the wizard doesnt show the tab.

What im doing wrong? is there a way to achieve what im trying to do? How could I show and hide the tab from the bean?

Thanks

Comment: I agree i would expect that to work except I am pretty sure Search Expression Framework "@form" can't be used server side.  Can you try using the real form like ":frmWizard" or whatever it is?

Comment: Hello, I tried with the real name of the form but is not working. I have tried lots of things but anything works. Is like wizard cant be updated from the bean. Right now im using a checkbox in the screen, it was the only way to achieve this